# Why do i get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error while reading data from a file and trying to insert it into a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, file-read

my file format is "name, password"

When i'm trying to print the username_file and password_file they appear to be read fine. But as soon as i call LinkedInsert(); always gives me a segmentation fault.

```
void read_data(FILE *io_fptr, ListPointer *List, ListPointer PredPtr)
{

    int nscan;
    char  username_file[20], password_file[15];

    while(nscan=fscanf(io_fptr,"%19[^,], %14[^ ]", username_file, password_file)!=EOF)
    {
       LinkedInsert(List, username_file,password_file, PredPtr);
       
    }

}
```

and this is the LinkedInsert function in case its needed:

```
void LinkedInsert(ListPointer *List, ListElementType username[],ListElementType password[], ListPointer PredPtr)

{
    ListPointer TempPtr;

   TempPtr= (ListPointer)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
   strcpy(TempPtr->username,username);
   strcpy(TempPtr->password, password);

    if (PredPtr==NULL) {   
        TempPtr->Next = *List;
        *List = TempPtr;
    }
    else {
        TempPtr->Next = PredPtr->Next;
        PredPtr->Next = TempPtr;
    }
}
```

Here's some additional code for the types im using

```
typedef char ListElementType;           

typedef struct ListNode *ListPointer;

typedef struct ListNode
{
    ListElementType username[20];
    ListElementType password[15];
    ListPointer Next;
} ListNode;
```

Comment: `gdb` is your friend to identify the issue, don't cast malloc result. please share definition of ListPointer and ListNode

Comment: You assign 'TempPtr' to '*List', but this value goes in the trash at the end of the function, as 'List*' is passed by value.

Comment: Is the List pointer type the same size as ListNode?

Comment: Try `while(nscan=fscanf(io_fptr," %19[^,], %14[^ ]", username_file, password_file) == 2)` instead.  Space added, and `==2`.  If that does not help, post a [mcve].

Comment: I suspect the problem is using `!= EOF` rather than `== 2`.  Consider  `fscanf()`  finally reading a rump `'\n'` into `username_file` and returning 1.  Then `strcpy(TempPtr->password, password);` dies as `password` is garbage.

Comment: `LinkedInsert` is confused on too many levels to describe.

Comment: What are the goal of `ListPointer` and `ListElementType` try to remove them this will improve readability of your code

Comment: regarding; `typedef struct ListNode *ListPointer;`  It is a very poor programming practice to hide pointers in `typedef` statements